# SQL query, AVG and COUNT on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need a query, the query that i used doesn't work the way i want for some reason

Here's all the tables involved in the query.

[image: sql tables for the query]

**Here's the query i want :**
Show a list of books with their average ratings and its number of recommendations

result should be like this :
[image: result of query]

**What i already tried :**

```
SELECT        book.isbn, AVG(ratings.rating) AS [AVG Ratings], COUNT(recommend.isbn) AS [Number of recommendation]
FROM            book INNER JOIN
                         recommend ON book.isbn = recommend.isbn INNER JOIN
                         ratings ON book.isbn = ratings.isbn
GROUP BY book.isbn
```

But it didn't work, somehow the the AVG rating works great, but the # of recommendations does not, it conflicts with the ratings table.

here's what the result is:

[image]

However when i try each one alone, everything works great like this :

for AVG ratings :

```
SELECT        book.isbn, AVG(ratings.rating) AS [AVG Ratings]
FROM            book INNER JOIN
                         ratings ON book.isbn = ratings.isbn
GROUP BY book.isbn
```

Here's the result :

[image]

And for the # of recommendations :

```
SELECT        book.isbn, COUNT(recommend.isbn) AS [Number of recommendation]
FROM            book INNER JOIN
                         recommend ON book.isbn = recommend.isbn
GROUP BY book.isbn
```

Here's the result :

[image]

**So i want a query to combine the two views into one view**

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Obviously, use dummy data if it's sensitive in some way, but keep it coherent.

Comment: Yes, please add some sample tables and rows for your question as @Strawberry mentioned.

Comment: how can this be both mysql and sql-server?

Comment: For `AVG()`, you're actually counting all the rows multiple times, so it's doing more work than it needs.  The math actually works out, in most instances (and it's unlikely you'll get sufficient rows for it to be a problem).

Comment: Well, you could simply combine the two queries that worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get accurate results, then you need to do the aggregations before the join:

```
SELECT b.isbn, r.AvgRating, re.NumRecommendation
FROM  book b LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT r.isbn, AVG(r.rating) as AvgRating
       FROM rating r
       GROUP BY r.isbn
      ) r
      ON b.isbn = r.isbn LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT r.isbn, COUNT(*) as NumRecommendation
       FROM recommendation r
       GROUP BY r.isbn
      ) re
      on b.isbn = r.isbn ;
```

Note that I also switched to left outer joins, so you will get results for all books, even those that are missing either ratings or recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  book.isbn, 
  IFNULL(AVG(ratings.rating),"Not yet rated") AS [AVG Ratings],
  IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT recommend.iduse),0) AS [Number of recommendation]
FROM
  book
  LEFT JOIN recommend ON book.isbn = recommend.isbn 
  LEFT JOIN ratings ON book.isbn = ratings.isbn
GROUP BY book.isbn
```

Should to the trick:

- Counting the distinct users recommending a book will fix the cartesian product issue
- Left joins with the usual `IFNULL()` plumbing will make it work on books that have either no recommendations or no ratings

Comment: I would imagine that the average rating would be incorrect, due to the cartesian product produced for each isbn.

Comment: I thought so too, but turns out the problem is confined to the 2nd join - mysql pecularity or bad error reproduction on my side? Anyway, I'd do it in two queries (and maybe cache values to columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can use the over clause:

```
SELECT 
  B.isbn, 
  AVG(ra.rating) OVER (PARTITION BY B.isbn) AS [AVG RATE],
  COUNT(re.isbn) OVER (PARTITION BY B.isbn) AS [RECOMMEND COUNT]
FROM Book B
LEFT JOIN recommend re ON B.isbn = re.isbn 
LEFT JOIN ratings ra ON B.isbn = ra.isbn
```

Comment: This will not produce correct results due to the cartesian product problem.  In this case, both numbers will be off.